# Python3-dev version conflict on fresh 18.04 install

Tags: 18.04, python3

As with other posts in this stack exchange, I'm having issues with installing python3-dev on a fresh  install of Ubuntu (18.04) that is running a pre-installed python3 (3.6.9-1~18.04).  Many of the recommended fixes in those posts that I have tried have worked, such as uninstalling and reinstalling python3.  I've had to restore my laptop to the factory defaults twice now because apt ended up breaking much of the operating system by modifying python3.  Aptitude also could not resolve the conflicts.

More specifically, when I attempt to do `sudo apt install python3-dev` I get the following:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree      
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 python3-dev : Depends: python3 (= 3.6.5-3) but 3.6.7-1~18.04 is to be installed
               Depends: libpython3-dev (= 3.6.5-3) but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: python3.6-dev (>= 3.6.5-2~) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Here is the output of running `sudo apt update`:

```
Hit:1 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease
Hit:2 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease                    
Hit:3 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease                    
Ign:4 http://oem.archive.canonical.com/updates bionic-oem InRelease            
Ign:5 http://dell.archive.canonical.com/updates bionic-dell-beaver-osp1-gendry InRelease
Hit:6 http://oem.archive.canonical.com/updates bionic-oem Release
Ign:7 http://dell.archive.canonical.com/updates bionic-dell-service InRelease
Hit:9 http://dell.archive.canonical.com/updates bionic-dell InRelease
Hit:10 http://dell.archive.canonical.com/updates bionic-dell-beaver-osp1-gendry Release
Hit:12 http://dell.archive.canonical.com/updates bionic-dell-service Release
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree      
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up to date.
```

and the output for `sudo apt upgrade`:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree      
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

I'd appreciate any help in figuring out how I can resolve these issues.  Upgrading to the latest version of Ubuntu (20.04) is not an option right now.

Comment: I appreciate the suggestion.  I've provided the recommended outputs.  As well, Python 3.6.9 came pre-installed, as I noted above, and is the default version when doing a factory reset.  I haven't changed it at all.

Comment: Did you run the `sudo apt update` first?  `python3-dev` from your paste provide match the current package (3.6.7-1~18.04), ie.  https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic-updates/python3-dev https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=python3-dev&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=python3&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all  It looks like you'd not ran `sudo apt update` & then fully upgraded your system `sudo apt full-upgrade` as your messages are *out-of-date*.  Do you have `updates` enabled for official archives?  (I don't see those lines!)

Comment: Can you additionally add the output of `apt policy python3 python3-dev`?

I believe the issue is somehow you don't have the `bionic-updates` repository as a source.

Comment: Thank you to both of you!  I went into the Software Updater application and found that, for some reason, the check boxes for the various `install updates from` options were unchecked by default; this is surprising to me.  I checked those options, then let Ubuntu install all of the available updates.  I was then able to run `sudo apt install python3-dev` successfully.